# Alternate way for Starling/Workling for background process in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, background-process

Currently we are using starling/workling in our rails application.But we are facing some issues with starling/workling background process.So we are thinking to replace it with some other better process. Could you please let me know alternate background process for rails.

Answer (score 1):

You have several ways of doing that, you can find video tutorials [here](http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=32).

Comment: Thanks for sharing this link.
Could you please let me know the best one for background process.